# Performance tuning. stop fade-in from white page when loading an angular page

Tags: angularjs, performance

I have an angularjs application and I am trying to improve its perceptual perfomance on load.

One annoying thing is that the page starts off as a blank page and seems to load everything before page slowly fades in.

I would much rather have some html load and let the xhr data subsequently populate as it comes.

Here's a visual of what I mean:
https://youtu.be/b1GxGJ0BUQU

I checked for the term cloak anywhere in the app and I could not find it. I also checked if there were any resolve attributes on the route and found nothing.

Any advice on improving this perceptual performance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: have you tried using ng-init method ? I would suggest have your http calls run via init.  That way your page will be present before calling xhr

Comment: @Don I've used ng-init for setting variables before repeaters but not sure how I could use it to get rid of the blank screens. can you explain? If you're talking about not loading the panel things, the panels are populated using ng-repeat of ctrl.jobs; I've already tried setting ctrl.jobs = [] and not even making that xhr call.

Answer (score 1):

This fade-in has to be coded somewhere, and we cannot help you find it without the code. You need to understand what triggers that fade-in, so that you could remove it to immediately display the page.

If the code is too big to be understood, one option is to stop the code execution as soon as it starts - for instance add a `debugger;` statement before the rest - and then use your browser developper tools to inspect the HTML: most likely there is a component full size and plain white on top of the rest, which gets removed at some point. Track its id or class names to find where it is dealt with in your code.

Again these are just advices but we cannot really help you understand a code/HTML that we can't see.

Comment: you hit it on the nail that the codebase is big and so I can't post, unfortunately. I will try your tactic to catch the fade in, but I agree with you that that's what I think it is. I just cant find it! Hopefully, your trick may help me.